# A numeral (+ of)

Tags: numerals

**If we have three groups of people with 100 hundred people in each group, do we need to use "of"?**

1) There are three hundreds of people in the street.

or

2) There are three hundreds people in the street.

**Another context with the superlative adjective form.**

3) I have seen more than three hundred of the happiest people in the street.

*Am I correct to consider that "of" can't be omitted in sentence 3 because of "the happiest"?*

Answer (score 3):

1. No. It is not idiomatic to use either *hundreds* or *of* when a specific number precedes the *hundred*.

So.

> hundreds of people

is fine, as is

> two hundred people

but not

> two hundreds of people.

The same applies to *thousand*, *million*, *dozen*, *score*. It doesn't apply to *pair*, *couple*, which always take *of* (except, I think, colloquially in some places in the US).

2. This is a different construction. *of* means *out of*, and cannot be omitted. *The* (rather than the superlative) makes it a definite group, that you are selecting some from.

Comment: That's what I thought but wasn't sure. Would it be correct to say "There are three hundreds people in the street" meaning "There are three groups of people, 100 people each"?

Comment: I hope you find it correct on its own "three hundreds people" with the meaning of three groups of 100 each.

Comment: @user1425 That sounds strange. You would more commonly say, "There are three groups of a hundred people on the street."

Comment: @user1425: _Three hundreds of people_ is grammatical, but very unusual. I guess it _might_ mean "three specific groups of a hundred people", but I'm not sure. _Three hundreds people_ is not grammatical.

Comment: @ Jason Bassford I suppose it does sound strange. But that's exactly why it should be cleared up. Grammar is strange sometimes.